# Server Sent Events don't work in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, server-sent-events, playframework-2.3

The following codes don't work in Play framework 2.3

controllers.NotificationHandler.sendNotification():

```
 def sendNotification = Action {
    request =>
      val currentdate = new java.util.Date()
      Ok("data: " + currentdate.toString())
        .as( "text/event-stream")
        .withHeaders("Content-Type"->"text/event-stream")
        .withHeaders("Cache-Control"->"no-cache")
        .withHeaders("Connection"->"keep-alive")
 }
```

The JS code:

```
var event = new EventSource("@controllers.NotificationHandler.sendNotification()");
event.addEventListener('message', function( event ) {
    alert(event.data);
} );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the js part to use the route to your controller instead of the controller it self:

```
var event = new EventSource("@routes.NotificationHandler.sendNotification()");
   event.addEventListener('message', function( event ) {
       alert(event.data);
   }  
);
```

Your controller doesn't seem to need SSE as it sends only one value, a more complete exemple is to create an enumertaor and use it to send SSE, as shown here:

```
def sendNotification = Action{
   val producer = Enumerator.generateM[String](Promise.timeout(Some(Random.nextString(5)),3 second))
   Ok.chunked(producer &> EventSource()).as("text/event-stream")
}
```

To send a message once it's available you can use Concurrent.broadcast

```
val (producer,channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]
def sendNotification = Action{
       Ok.chunked(producer &> EventSource()).as("text/event-stream")
    }
```

And then use channel.push(yourData) to push data to the browser. Be aware that in this exemple channel is a global object.